# Capturing build date in deployment pipleine

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to capture the build date of an artifact to be logged elsewhere. Join me on my convoluted journey to solve this.

I know we have these handy variables

```
$(Build.SourceVersion)
$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

*EDIT: These are not as handy as I thought. These are just the identifers for the deploy pipeline, not the original build pipeline that generated the artefact. So I can repeatedly deploy the same build / artefact, and these numbers will continue to increment, having no relevance to what I built - I'm not interested in that.*

But there is no build date. I know it can be derived from the BuildNumber but it seems over the top to call a REST API to get that info.

So in my build pipeline I am writing Get-Date to a file then publishing that as an artefact

```
- powershell: (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") | Out-File -FilePath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\BuildDt.txt
```

Then I pick that up in the deploy pipeline and save to a variable using the kludgy `Write-Host` method

```
  - stage: DownloadDBArtifacts
    displayName: Download DB Artifacts
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
    - job: GetArtefacts
      displayName: Get Artefacts
      steps:    
      - download: DBBuild
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Get Build timestamp
        name: GetBuildDt
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            $BuildDt = Get-Content -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace)\DBBuild\drop\BuildDt.txt
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildDt;isoutput=true]$BuildDt"
            Write-Host "##[debug]Artifact Creation Date: $BuildDt"
```

This is done in stage *DownloadDBArtifacts*

Now I need to use it in a later stage, that is also in a child YAML template

I beleive this is the syntax for extracting the variable:

```
stageDependencies.DownloadDBArtifacts.GetArtefacts.outputs['GetBuildDt.BuildDt']
```

I'm having difficulty getting this recognised in later stages. Here is a subsequent stage that tries to capture the value based on examples from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages

```
  - stage: DeployDBtoTST
    displayName: Deploy DB to TST
    dependsOn: DownloadDBArtifacts
    variables: 
    - group: vgTST
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployDBtoTST
      displayName: Deploy DB to TST
      environment: TST Environment
      variables:
        BuildDt: $[ stageDependencies.DownloadDBArtifacts.GetArtefacts.outputs['GetBuildDt.BuildDt'] ]
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - powershell: |
                Write-Host "var: $(BuildDt)"
```

however the value is not being passed through as the final powershell step just produces this output:

> var:

Comment: From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies), the syntax should be : `dependencies.DownloadDBArtifacts.outputs['GetArtefacts.printvar.BuildDt']`

Comment: In the link I posted it says _To use the output from a different stage at the job level, you use the stageDependencies syntax_, and there's an example of the syntax I'm using.

Comment: But then this link implies it's the `dependencies` context which I actually tried first, but I will try it again tomorrow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables

Comment: What I've learnt so far: `isoutput=true` means the variable is not visible in the _same_ stage. So you can't write a troubleshooting script to check the value in the same stage.

Comment: Changing syntax to $[ `dependencies.DownloadDBArtifacts.outputs['GetArtefacts.GetBuildDt.BuildDt'] ]` makes no difference. In a normal programming language I would try to dump the contents if the `dependencies` and `stageDependencies` contexts but not sure how that is done

Comment: This also indicates I should use `stageDependencies` https://wsbctechnicalblog.github.io/sharing-variables-with-stages-and-jobs.html

Comment: I've used the `SET` command to dump environment variables and I'm not seeing anything that lines up with what is mentioned in this article: https://wsbctechnicalblog.github.io/sharing-variables-with-stages-and-jobs.html This has been an utter waste of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Capturing build date in deployment pipleine

I could reproduce this issue with your YAML sample.

To resolve this issue, please update your `DownloadDBArtifacts` by following code:

```
  - stage: DownloadDBArtifacts
    displayName: Download DB Artifacts
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
    - job: GetArtefacts
      displayName: Get Artefacts
      steps:    
      - download: DBBuild
      - task: InlinePowershell@1
        displayName: 'Get Artefacts'
        inputs:
          Script: |
            $BuildDt = Get-Content -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace)\DBBuild\drop\BuildDt.txt
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildDt;isOutput=true]$BuildDt"
        name: GetBuildDt
```

The test result:

[image]

**Update:**

> Sorry, I tried changing the DownloadDBArtifacts as you mentioned above
> andit made no difference.

You have a slight letter error in your code that is causing the issue.

One is  `name: GetBuiltDt` and another is `outputs['GetBuildDt.BuildDt'] ]`. The **`Built`** should be **`Build`**：

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking Leo. I haven't yet tested your script but looking at the powershell code, `$BuildDt` is never assigned a value in the powershell code, but it is being used to set a variable, so I don't understand how this would actually work.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Sorry, there was an editing error in the code module when the answer was written. I have updated it, please check.

Comment: Again I haven't tested but the only difference between this and the original code is that you are using much older `InlinePowershell@1` instead of `PowerShell@2` as well as different casing for `isOutput`. Is this the actual difference?

Comment: Sorry, I tried changing the DownloadDBArtifacts as you mentioned above andit made no difference.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I've spent a long, long, long time researching this strange issue, I compared your code letter by letter with the correct code, and finally, luckily found a slight letter error in your code, you can check my update answer for some more details.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts. I'm so sorry to say that I picked up that spelling mistake and fixed it but neglected to update my sample code. It does raise an important question: do you know if there is any possible way to enumerate any of these values, i.e. can you enumerate `stageDependencies` or `stageDependencies.DownloadDBArtifacts` or `stageDependencies.DownloadDBArtifacts.GetArtefacts.outputs`? So much of DevOps/YAML is jus putting in tasks that eho things just to troubleshoot.

Comment: I read threads like this https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743#issuecomment-643469964 and I realise... this really is confusing, badly documented and inconsistent. If I could just inspect / enumerate those "contexts" I ould make some progress but I am now at the stage of trying random syntaxes

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, So, the previous issue in this thread have been resolved? If yes, you could **accept it as answer**. And for the newest question in your comment, would you please open a new thread with more info? Since this question is not the same question as the original one, one thread per question is recommended, plus I've spent too much time on this thread and don't have much extra time to continue working on your new question. very sorry. If you open a new question, the community will be more willing to help you and more people will notice your new question

Comment: I really do appreciate the time you have spent on this. I didn't make it clear that it still doesn't function, even with that typo fixed up. I simply cannot get this to work. If I have time I'll try a much simpler repo. My other comments in this thread are all about trying to resolve this particular issue. Unfortunately there appears to be some kind of worldwide DevOps issue at the moment so I can't proceed right now

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Still unsuccessful? So weird, I use exactly the code you provided (just fix the wrong letters) and it's ok on my side. There may be a problem caused by an ignored difference. You are welcome to provide a new sample.

Comment: OK, I had one last try and it's now working. I think your observation is correct in that a variable was mispelt somewhere. Thanks for your effort and for sticking with this.